# Caller ID spoofing or change caller ID?

Tags: iphone, applications, websites, voip

Is there a subscription site or iPhone application for changing caller id or caller id spoofing? In other words I want to call someone, but I want to change my number (for example 000000 or 111111). How can I do this?

Comment: **Note**: fraud or trickery are not the only reasons for wanting to do this.  A businessman making calls when he is out of the office (from his cell phone, for example) might want the caller ID to show his usual office number.

Comment: Are you looking to reliably use the same "different" number or be able to select a new number with ease (on a case by case basis)? Also - is this worldwide or from a specific carrier in a specific country?

Comment: GEdgar this is what I want, in fact I have two numbers one of them ables me to make free local mobiles and landlines but the other one is too expensive so I want to make call divert from expensive one to cheap one to receive all calls cause there is a feature in the expensive one which its calling 3 mobile numbers for free and then I will active call divert from expensive one to cheap one. now I want to make call from cheap number but the caller id will display as my main number(expensive one)

Answer (score 2):

Most carriers support the `*67`-prefix when calling a phone number. 
This does not change caller ID but at least it hides it.

Comment: This suppresses the number and doesn't insert a "fake" one as requested. I don't understand if the OP really wants a fake number to show so that the other party doesn't see blocked but instead has some actual number transmitted.

Comment: i did point that out in my answer...

Answer (score 1):

If you're eligible for Google Voice, you can sign up for an alternate phone number, place a call from the web with your Google Voice account, and Google Voice will call the number you want to dial as well as your phone.  Then, don't have calls to your Google Voice number forwarded to your phone.  If the caller obtains your Google Voice number from caller ID, they will be able to leave messages but not call you back directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick Google search revealed the following:

- [Free Caller ID Spoofing](http://freecalleridspoofing.com/)
- [Telespoof](http://www.telespoof.com/)
- [SpoofCard](http://www.spoofcard.com/)
- [Spooftel](http://www.spooftel.com/)
- [Spoofapp](http://spoofapp.com/) - iPhone app
- [iSpoof](http://thebigboss.org/new-application-ispoof) - free iPhone app
- [Here](http://www.squidoo.com/spoofingcallerid) is a Squidoo article about Caller ID spoofing.

Answer (score -2):

use "call recorder" for iphone. best app to change caller id of your choice.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.