# Schedule disabling of outgoing Caller ID

Tags: iphone, caller-id

Is it possible with or without an additional app to dynamically disable my caller ID on an iPhone?

I would like to suppress my number for calls I make for my employer from my private device. These usually happen in specific hours during work days and go to numbers not found in my contacts. If possible I would like to transmit the number of my companyʼs call center instead. Currently, I switch off the feature manually each morning and on again in the afternoon, but I frequently forget to do one or the other, which annoys friends whom I call in the evening.

Since iOS 10 there is the `CallKit` framework available for app developers. If I read the API documentation correctly, there is no official way to influence the transmission of caller ID information, i.e. suppressing your outgoing phone number or spoofing it. (The respective answers in  [Caller ID spoofing or change caller ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/23316/67264) apparently rely on paid third-party services.) The only way I see would be to transparently add codes like `#31#` when placing a call.