# iPhone 11: Unknown name showing up without number?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I received a text message from someone who I have never texted/talked with previously (not on phone, social media, email, anything). For some reason, their name shows up in `Messages` yet when I try to access the contact info page, there is no number (or any other info for that matter) provided.

How can the phone detect a person's name (still in my messages) but not have the number? Especially since I have never had any contact with this person before?

EDIT: After some research, it appears that this is a fairly common scam. The scammer sends a text message that includes an e-mail in attempt to pull more information out of you.

Still, how is it possible for them to send an undetectable message to me? And why does my iPhone give them a name (which can potentially put them on "friendly" terms)?

Comment: [Caller ID spoofing or change caller ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23316/caller-id-spoofing-or-change-caller-id)

Comment: How is that related to my question? The link you associated to my question seems to assume there was a number shown (albeit changed)--in my question, I received a text from someone who seemingly has a hidden number. Furthermore, in my question, there is an element of a name being associated with this hidden number. The other question does not have this element entirely.

Comment: See this line in the linked question: *"...the response arrives from Info (e.g. hence the iOS Messages app shows it in a new thread,..."* This is the exact same case as yours. An sms comes from a name, human or machine, and has no number.